# Avoid local storage restore

Tags: javascript, cookies, vuejs2, local-storage

I have a Vue SPA app+ Spring boot services that use token + session cookies solution to handle user sessions.

If a user logs into service `A`, it sets a cookie `Ca` in the browser and service `B` uses this cookie to send a request to service A, verify the cookie and obtain a temporary token(which would be used by service B for subsequent requests).

This token is stored in the local storage. Local storage and cookies will be cleared upon user logout.

But if a user presses the browser `back` button after logging out, the local storage gets restored and users can still consume services with the token.

Is there a way to permanently clear the local storage to prevent this?

Comment: I'm guessing you already have some sort of a route change guard, you could re-use it to ensure the localstorage has a token before moving to any of the `authorized` routes.

Comment: I doubt the local storage is being "restored". When you go back to a page in your recent history it will be loaded from a local cache and won't be loaded from scratch, to improve speed navigating through the history.

Comment: Well it restores the token removed on the logout

Comment: @varunagarwal not clear, I already check every request for the token if that's what you mean